# How to create a LEMP stack with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

i want to create a LEMP stack with docker-compose for local web development but i've got in some troubles...

The configuration files i wrote:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
                - "8080:80"
        volumes:
                - ./web:/web
                - ./mysite.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template
        links:
                - php
        command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
php:
        image: php:7-fpm
        volumes:
                - ./web:/web
```

**mysite.template**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /web;
        index index.php index.html;
        server_name default_server;

     location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /web$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

The problem is that when i try to open `http://localhost:8080` the result is an *Access Denied*

How can i fix it?

*EDIT:*
This is the nginx container error log:

```
nginx_1  | 2017/11/01 13:21:25 [error] 8#8: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '/web' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream
```

Comment: Using the code you have provided works for me. Did you create `web/index.html`?

Comment: @pinny87 yeah, it works for html, but not for php code... i've tried a simple `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` but it show me Access Denied

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get your example working by changing your `docker-compose.yml` to:

```
nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
                - "8080:80"
        volumes:
                - ./web:/web
                - ./mysite.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        links:
                - php
php:
        image: php:7-fpm
        volumes:
                - ./web:/web
```